# Encoding/decoding issue of a string in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, decode, encode

I am trying to display the below string in the HTML browser but the moment browser encounter with custom tag like "" in the string, it just skip that.

I tried encodeURIComponent() and later tried to decodeURIComponent in my HTML template but did not work.

I even tried to sanitize the HTML by creating an PIPE like below but no luck.

```
transform(v: string): SafeHtml {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
    }
```

somehow, browser is skipping the the element like  in the string.

***following is the string***

```
“The endpoint is browser-based, rather than RESTful. Therefore it could 
     result in the following different scenarios,↵1. SUCCESS 
    (response_type=code)↵> redirect_uri?code=<authorization-code>&scope= 
    <resource-owner-approved-scopes>[&state=<state-provided-by-the-client>]."
```

[image: Image for jacob]

Comment: use ' ` ' instead of  ' " '? Maybe this can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: What are you trying to do with the string? Inserting it into an `innerHTML` property, perhaps?

Comment: you mean putting the string between back-tick and not double quotes. I am getting this string from server.

Comment: @jacob yes, I am inserting it into an div using innerHTML.

Comment: Your quotes don't match.

Comment: @StackSlave quotes don't match?? it is a string in double quotes. I did not get your question.

Comment: One quote is curly, the other is not.

Comment: @StackSlave I am sorry, I still do not see the missing curly.

Answer (score 3):

Never insert *text* with `innerHTML`; only insert *HTML* with `innerHTML`.

Browsers nowadays have a [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property:

```
yourDiv.textContent = stringFromServer;
```

Also, just to clear up the common mistake you and many other developers make, `encodeURIComponent` is meant to encode a string for *insertion into a URL*, not insertion into *HTML*. Same goes with `encodeURI` (which you probably should never use anyway).

**Update**:

As stated in your comments, you're actually wanting to *transform* the text into HTML using some rules rather than inserting plain text into your HTML, which will do the typical whitespace normalization rules.

There are many options for this. Here are two:

1. Still insert just the plain text, but set the CSS style in the container to `white-space: pre`. This changes the way that whitespace is rendered, so newlines cause line breaks.
2. Split your original string, then intersperse your div with text nodes and `<br/>` elements.

Code for the latter could look something like this:

```
function insertFormattedText(container, text) {
  const chunks = text.split('\n');
  chunks.forEach((chunk, i) => {
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chunk));
    if (i < chunks.length - 1) {
      container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      // Equivalent of `&nbsp;&nbsp;`
      container.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0\u00A0'));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: actually I am displaying it as an HTML only. this string I get from server. than I replace "↵" newline symbol with "<br /> &nbsp;nbsp;" to  make it look aligned and readable. but if I use  textContent property, it will display everything as text and no formatting applies.

Comment: So you're not wanting to really _encode_ the string, then, but rather _transform_ it into HTML. Will add to my answer.

Comment: I am doing something in similar lines. I am using Regex instead of js function like this;   obj.description =  obj.description.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;");  but this ignores the  element inside string ( like <authorization-code> )  to get render on the browser. please let me know, if you got my point otherwise I can add an image of the render content

Comment: The problem with that is you're only converting _some_ of the string to valid HTML. The rules to convert the rest of it are complicated. It's much easier to let the DOM do the dirty work of encoding the string. You could maybe do a `.split` with that regex if you want to take my approach.

Comment: I wonder, is there only way to put this type of string under <code> . OR <pre> as browser treats them in such weird way.

Comment: You could put it in a `pre`, but you can get that same effect with that `white-space: pre` style if you wanted the line break stuff. The indentation part wouldn't be covered; I'm not sure how married you are to that.

Comment: Yeah, I think, I will go with <pre> for now as showing everything is more important than some formatting stuff. Thanks for all your help.